# How to plot in matlab both distributions in the same graph, including axis labels and a legend to distinguish the two distributions

Tags: matlab, distribution, gaussian

Considering two normal (Gaussian) distributions: the first is characterized by μ=10, σ=3. The second is characterized by μ=10, σ=1

Comment: To get yourself started with this, read the [Getting Started with MATLAB tutorial on plotting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/plots.html).

Comment: yeah, but i'm not sure on how to set this up with the characterizations?

Comment: While homework problems are not disallowed on StackOverflow, you should take extra measured to ensure that people do not feel that we are solving your homework for you. See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions. Also please take the [tour] and read [ask] and cohere to those, this will help you get answers in the future and you will avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the Probability Density Function of these two distributions. You can calculate it by using this code,

```
function f = gauss_distribution(x, mu, s)
p1 = -.5 * ((x - mu)/s) .^ 2;
p2 = (s * sqrt(2*pi));
f = exp(p1) ./ p2;
```

Suppose you have two dataset x1 and x2. Then,

```
f1 = gauss_distribution(x1,10,3);
f2 = gauss_distribution(x2,10,1);
```

Now the plotting can be done like this,

```
figure;
plot(x1,f1);
hold on;
plot(x2,f2,'r');
xlabel('name of label');
legend('1st dataset', '2nd dataset');
```

Comment: that was helpful, thanks. Now it asks to calculate p(x>11) for each distribution using Matlab’s normcdf() function. You can either use the ‘upper’ parameter or subtract p(x<11) from 1 to find the answer.

Comment: p = normcdf(x,mu,s)

Comment: (1 - p(x=11) ) will give that. By the way, if the answer is useful you can accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB has greatly simplified this process for many distributions with the [`makedist()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/makedist.html), [`pdf()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.pdf.html), and [`cdf()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.cdf.html) command. Code and resulting plots below for reference.

```
pd1 = makedist('Normal',10,3);
pd2 = makedist('Normal',10,1);
X = [0:.01:20]';

% PDF plot
figure, hold on, box on
p(1) = plot(X,pdf(pd1,X),'b-','DisplayName','N(\mu = 10, \sigma = 3)')
p(2) = plot(X,pdf(pd2,X),'k-','DisplayName','N(\mu = 10, \sigma = 1)')
title('Two Normal Distributions (PDFs)')
xlabel('X')
ylabel('PDF')
legend('show')
set(p,'LineWidth',2.2)

% CDF plot
figure, hold on, box on
p(1) = plot(X,cdf(pd1,X),'b-','DisplayName','N(\mu = 10, \sigma = 3)')
p(2) = plot(X,cdf(pd2,X),'k-','DisplayName','N(\mu = 10, \sigma = 1)')
title('Two Normal Distributions (CDFs)')
xlabel('X')
ylabel('CDF')
legend('show','Location','southeast')
set(p,'LineWidth',2.2)
```

[image: PDFs]

[image: CDFs]